# mouseover/mouseout Videojs Sharing objects at runtime

Tags: video, video-streaming, video.js

Is there a way to mouseover/mouseout the video controls on the videojs player at runtime (e.g.  myPlayer.on("mouseover", myFunc); myPlayer.on("mouseout", myFunc);).
Any ideas how to do this? Thanks!

Comment: you may try myPlayer.el().on(xxxx).  I believe that myPlayer.on() only catches events thrown from video.js not native hover events and what not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me on chrome.

```
mPlayer = videojs("example_video", {});
mPlayer.controlBar.on("mouseover", function() { console.log("over");});
mPlayer.controlBar.on("mouseout", function() { console.log("out");});`
```

Comment: You need to be more specific. Clicking items in the control bar works fine for me on chrome on win/mac/linux. http://jsbin.com/uqukot/6/edit

Comment: Looks to me like your social icons are outside the video element, so I'm guessing that when you hover over them, you're triggering a mouseout of the video player, causing them to be hidden.

Comment: Tellme anyone how to fix this issue?